# Configuring Your App For OpenEars in xcode 3.2.6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, configuration, openears

i configured the Openers successfully with the help of this link.  http://www.politepix.com/openears/configuring.

however they are documented "Configuring Your App For OpenEars" only in Xcode 4.

i am using xcode 3.2.6 cant able to use  Openears library in my application using this document .may i knoe any other document links to explain  "Configuring Your App For OpenEars" only in Xcode 3.2.6.can any one help me please.i stuck in here in the document.cant able to do this process in xcode 3.2.6.this following steps i can do with xcode 3.2.6...please help me

**steps that i cant do in xcode 3.2.6**

---

Step 2: From Xcode, select your blue project icon for your app (not the OpenEarsLibrary project) in the Project Navigator and select its target under the TARGETS header in the left-hand column in the editor. Navigate to the tab Build Phases. Click “Target Dependencies”.

Click the plus button for Target Dependencies. Then select the gray OpenEarsLibrary icon in that dialog and click “Add”.

Step 3: In the same view, with the app target still selected underneath the header TARGETS in the left-hand pane of the editor window, navigate to the Build Phases pane and select “Link Binary With Libraries”

Tapping the plus button, add the OpenEars framework libOpenEarsLibrary.a found in a folder at the top called workspace

please help by converting the above step according to the xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to this page: http://www.politepix.com/openears/gettingstarted and find the phrase "It is still possible to download the previous version of OpenEars and its distribution contains instructions for Xcode 3 which should be very helpful for figuring out how to install current versions of OpenEars in Xcode 3". Download the previous version of OpenEars that is linked in the phrase "download the previous version of OpenEars".
2. Inside this download are the entire instructions for installing that older version of OpenEars in Xcode 3, saved as PDFs. The steps in the PDFs are *not* all the same as the instructions for the current version, but the part about linking the library (the specific part you are asking about) is still exactly the same. This explanation is in the PDF called "Configuring Your App For OpenEars.pdf" starting on page 4.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why you are still using Xcode 3 but what you need to do from memory is look for the root level targets expander icon in the tree. It looks like a red/white archery target and was usually after the resources folder. Expand it and right click what will probably be the sole target for your project. From there you will be offered the similar opportunity to add build phases.

If that doesnt exist in the contextual menu have a dig around in the Properties section for the target. It might be one of the tabs to add link dependancies.